# Finding date and adding specific number of business days to it

Tags: javascript, function, datetime, if-statement

I'm creating a macro within our application to grab a date field, add a specific number of business days to it, and then set a new field to said date. I want account for weekends and holidays so it bypasses them. I wrote this with the understanding that I can nest IF ELSE statements, is this correct? (I'm a beginner).. at the moment, it is not working. Hypothetically, this should work right?

To explain my process, first it will get the date from the field. Then check if its null, if so then set null. If not, continue to check if the day is a holiday, then check again for a 2nd holiday. if 2 holidays in a row, add 2 days. if only 1 holiday, add 1 day. after, check if that date is now saturday or sunday and if so,append 1 or 2 days respectively. Lastly, set new date field to myDate.

```
//create variables for each extended field
var reviewDueBy = los.GetField("ExtendedFields.Appraisal_Review_Due_By");
var receivedDate = los.GetField("ExtendedFields.Appraisal_Received_Date_2");

var fullDate = Date();
var myDate = fullDate.toDateString();

function timestamp(){
fullDate.setDate(receivedDate); //this adds X amount of days
myDate.setDate(myDate.getDate() + 2);

//if receivedDate equals a holiday, then equals second holiday, add 2. else, add 1.
if (reviewDueBy === null || reviewDueBy === undefined) {
    los.SetField(reviewDueBy, null);
} else { 
    if (/jan 1/i.test(myDate) || /may 25/i.test(myDate) || /jul 3/i.test(myDate) || /sep 7/i.test(myDate) || /oct 12/i.test(myDate) || /nov 26/i.test(myDate) || /dec 24/i.test(myDate)) {
        if (/nov 27/i.test(myDate) || /dec 25/i.test(myDate)) {
        myDate.setDate(myDate.getDate() + 2);
        } else { 
        myDate.setDate(myDate.getDate() + 1);
        }
    }
}


//if date equals Sat, then add 2 days. if Sun, add 1.
if (/sat/i.test(myDate)) {
    myDate.setDate(myDate.getDate() + 2);
} else if (/sun/i.test(myDate)) {
    myDate.setDate(myDate.getDate() + 1);
}

timestamp();
los.SetField(reviewDueBy, myDate);
```

I had originally wrote this without it being nested, but neither this nor that worked.

Comment: Yes nested if statements work in javascript, but I'm not sure what the question is. But it's an interesting problem. There are a bunch of plugins that already that already. I took my own stab at it http://jsfiddle.net/me2loveit2/10cpxymh/

Comment: You would have to integrate functionality for holidays, but my date library (http://depressedpress.com/javascript-extensions/dp_dateextensions/) does business days as is. Feel free to rip whatever you like out of it.

I had plans to allow for a parameter to allow "holidays". I'd expect a function that would accept a date and return TRUE (holiday) or FALSE (not a holiday). Maybe I should spend some time on that...

Comment: @PhilippWerminghausen Thanks. Do you mind explaining why it says //add an additional two if today is thursday or later// ? Im having trouble connecting it in my mind

Comment: Yeah that was actually a mistake. I updated it and actually completely rewrote it to be more robust and more reliable. Check it out: https://jsfiddle.net/me2loveit2/10cpxymh/